# What is the appropriate routingkey value for headers exchanges in RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

The Channel class (Java Client) provide three methods to publish a message, all of them with the routingkey parameter. The headers exchange does not need the routingkey.

If i pass a null value for the routingkey, the following exception is returned: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid configuration: 'routingKey' must be non-null."

However, if i pass an empty string it works. So the question is: Is it correct to use an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct to use empty string. The routing key is not used by headers exchanges as defined in AMQP protocol specification.

Most likely exception is thrown because driver doesn't know anything about setup and it's much safer to handle all errors, including potential errors, on client side.